# особенности Flex верстки

Tags: css

Почему средний блок больше на 2 пиксела?
https://jsfiddle.net/9d8LaLnd/

```css
.container {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap; 
  }
  .container div {
    height: 200px;
    flex: 1 1 250px;
    background: black;
    }
    .container div:nth-child(2) {
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px; 
     }
```

```html
<div class="container">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: больше в каком плане? проблема в хроме не воспроизводится

Comment: Вот линейкой на 1 пиксел больше, а хром показывает что одинакого https://yadi.sk/i/qYoUYB4x33dcHG

Comment: Так может это к линейке надо претензии предъявить, что у нее привязка к целым пикселям и она округляет?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Всё предъявил, больше не будет.